# Min timepoints to model longitudinal data with natural quadratic splines?

Tags: r, lme4, spline

I'm new to applying splines to longitudinal data, so here comes my question:
I've some longitudinal data on growing mice in 3 timepoints: at x, y and z months. It's known from the existent literature that the trajectories of growth in this type of data are usually better modeled in non-linear terms.
However, since I have only 3 timepoints, I wonder if this allows me to apply natural quadratic spline to age variable in my lmer model?

> edit:I mean is

```
  lmer<-mincLmer(File ~ ns(Age,2) * Genotype + Sex + (1|Subj_ID),data, mask=mask)
```

> a legit way to go around?

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question - I'm just a lonely PhD student without supervision, and I would be super-grateful for any advice!!!
Marina

Comment: hi, first of all welcome to SO! second: please add some reproducible data (with `dput()` you can subset your own data set). if the question is purely mathematical (although very interesting) maybe consider https://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

With the `nls()` function you can fit your data to whatever non-linear function you want. Then, from the biological point of view, probably your data is described by a Gompertz-like function (sigmoidal), but as you have only three time points, probably you can simplify these kind of functions into an exponential one. Try the following:

```
fit_formula <- independent_variable ~ a * exp(b * dependent_variable)
result <- nls(formula = fit_formula, data = your_Dataset)
```

It will probably give you an error the first times, something like `singular matrix gradient at initial estimates` ; if this happens, try adding the additional parameter `start`, where you provide different starting values for `a` and `b` more close to the true values. Remember that in your dataset, the column names must be equal to the names of the variables in the formula.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, Javier!!! That’s seems to be a very elegant solution.
Because of the longitudinal nature of my dataset, I want to use linear mixed effect model with subject ID as a random effect. And because my data are MRI scans, I am a bit restricted in formulas/packages I can use to fit models on MRI data – so it probably has to be MincLmer

Comment: So, what I was doing was:
  lmer<-mincLmer(File ~ ns(Age,2) * Genotype + Sex + (1|Subj_ID),data, mask=mask)
I had compared it with lmer<-mincLmer(File ~ Age * Genotype + Sex + (1|Subj_ID),data, mask=mask) with AIC. It seems that the first model explains more voxels in the final image than the second one. However, I’m not sure that I can use ns with only 3 timepoints.

Comment: What package are you using? It seems that mincLmer is not a base function of R

Comment: Thank you for your answer!'RMINC' for mincLmer to perform voxel-based statistics on MINC volumes and 'splines' for splines